# I need some advice with a Laravel docker setup

Tags: laravel, docker

I have a weird issue with dockerising a Laravel app for local dev. The PHP container needs the docker internal IP address for the mysql container as opposed to 127.0.0.1, otherwise it breaks with the following message:

`` SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = jr@m3u.com limit 1) ``

If I use the inspect command: `docker inspect -f '{{.Name}} - {{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $(docker ps -aq)`

I can see the 172 range IP addresses for each container, and if I change the mysql server to 172.31.0.2 in Laravel's .env file, the app then works fine.

Here's my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8888:80"
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 3310:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: docker
      MYSQL_USER: docker
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: docker
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel
```

Any help would be appreciated. :-)

Comment: Isnt your mysql a different container? So 127.0.0.1 would not work. Your setup is working as intended. Think of each new container as a different server.

Answer (score 1):

It is totally normal.

`127.0.0.1` would mean that the container executing the code could contact the database on the same container, which is not your case here since every service has their own container in your compose structure (which is great).

Like mentioned in the [network documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/), the containers join the same network by default, so they are able to reach each other by name or IP, on that docker internal network.

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

As far as I know, you have 3 options:

- Use the container name (`mysql`) as the hostname
- Provide the IP address of the container ( I do not recommend, because the IP is subject to change when you restart your containers. You would have to manually change the host IP every time your container IP changes - more or less every restart )
- Another approach would be to define static IPS on the docker-compose network. @see [the ip section](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#ipv4_address-ipv6_address)  of the network documentation.

At this point though, I would use the container name as the hostname. It is simple and clear.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's clear now what my mistake was.